# Is there a way to group documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am working with Elasticsearch using http requests and I am looking to see if there is a way to group documents before sending them to the client.

For background, Elasticseach has about 30 million documents per day and there will be spurts where the same document gets spammed a couple hundred times in a row. I want a way to group those hundreds of messages into one unique log so that i do not have to send hundreds of the same document in an http request.

Also, another thing that would help would be if you can flag spamming on the elasticsearch side of things. If a document appears hundreds of times in a minute, is there a way to set a value to spamming right in elasticsearch or is that on the client side.

I am currently looking into unique documents through aggregation and maybe that can be a start but I may also have the problem that it only returns the count of unique documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with duplicate documents, one method to solve this might be creating an [Ingest Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html).

You could create a pipeline that generates a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)) of the document, and set the `_id` to the value of that hash. Given that Elasticsearch IDs must be unique, all duplicate documents would get rejected by the Ingest Pipeline.

Look into the Elasticsearch [Fingerprint Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/fingerprint-processor.html) for some more guidance.